# How to add Smart Image View In android app page

Tags: android, xml

Now i am trying to add smart Image view on my app page,I have added

"android_smart_image_view.jar" in lib folder then now how should i directly add the smart image view from palette bar???

Comment: What's preventing you from adding `com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView android:id="@+id/my_image" />` directly to the layout file?

Comment: actually nothing serious error it is, bug is removed and problem is solved.... :)